# How to use PayPal's Express In-Context Checkout with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I'm following this [PayPal tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/enable-in-context-checkout/) about how to generate a PayPal button, but nothing works. The code it provides to make the button appear mysteriously worked only once for me, but after a refresh, it disappear and there's no Christ to make it appear again.

This is the code being executed inside of a React component

```
  class Storefronts extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="layout-wrapper">
          {this.props.location.pathname === '/shops' ? <Shops {...this.props}/> : <Basic {...this.props}/>}
          <script>
            window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
              paypal.checkout.setup('MERCHANTID', {
                environment: 'sandbox',
                container: 'test1',
              })
            }
          </script>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

This is a `Storefront` component that holds a `Shop`, and inside this one has a `Card` component. Basically, it's a shop that shows its products, and each product (`Card`) needs to have a button:

```
class Card extends Editor {
  render() {
    const {list} = this.props;
    let img = '/images/logo-v2-small.jpg';

    return (
      <Row>
      {list.map(item =>{
        return (
          <Col xs={6} md={3}>
            <Link to={{ pathname: '/shops/' + item.id }}>
              <Thumbnail src={img} alt={item.name}>
                <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                <p>{this.parseHtmlToReact(item.description)}</p>
                <p>{item.address}</p>
                <p>
                  <Button bsStyle="primary">Book</Button>
                  <a id="test1" href="/checkout"/> // The button should appear here.
                  <p className="pull-right">
                    {item.rating} 
                  </p>
                </p>
              </Thumbnail>
            </Link>
          </Col>
        )
      })}
      </Row>
    );
  }
}
```

There's nothing saying about its usage with React and no recent module for it.

Comment: Don't put the `<script>` in the render method. Put it in your HTML template or put its contents in `componentDidMount`. Then you should be able to access the paypal methods.

Comment: @FabianSchultz It seems it worked, now I see the button but I had to move the `a` tag to outside, or else it is not seen. Do you have more suggestions?

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative such as Stripe, I had written up [a step by step guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/) on how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own PayPal Button component.

```
class PayPalButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // you can take this value from a config.js module for example.
    this.merchantId = '6XF3MPZBZV6HU';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let container = this.props.id;
    let merchantId = this.merchantId;
    window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
      paypal.checkout.setup(merchantId, {
        locale: 'en_US',
        environment: 'sandbox',
        container: container,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <a id={this.props.id} href="/checkout" />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PayPalButton id="button" />, document.getElementById('View'));
```

**[Working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbacekkb/).**

Comment: Very nice, it is working now, thank you! Just one thing, the button is only shown when I refresh the page, and if I save a file that makes it reload, it disappears. What could that be?

Comment: I think that was because I was missing the `async` flag on the PayPal's `checkout.js` script tag. Updated my code.

Comment: I always had it, but it still happens, I meant in my code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and direction, I have just also created a true react-paypal-express-checkout library, post here just to give reference for anyone who's gonna need to work with Paypal in reactjs